# Quantum Zeno Effect and Many Worlds Interpretation (Plus Quantum Eraser)

Tags: quantum-interpretations, quantum-eraser

What's the Many-Worlds interpretation of the Quantum Zeno effect and does its interpretation somehow relate to the Many-Worlds interpretation of the quantum eraser experiment? If so, how? I know this question isn't phrased very precisely. I'm hoping for an explanation in simple terms that will help me to understand both effects better, since they both are puzzling me when looking at them with Many-Worlds.